# Check if text area is empty or not except placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to find the div is empty except the placeholder element/value

when div is empty

```
<div id="textarea"  contenteditable="true">
    <span id="textarea-placeholder" data-text="Enter comment"></span>
</div>
```

when div has content

```
<div id="textarea"  contenteditable="true">
    <span id="textarea-placeholder" data-text="Enter comment"></span>
    abc text inside div
    <a></a> //other elements
    <p></p> // other elements
</div>
```

tried following

```
$("#textarea").text().length) == 0

$('#textarea').find('*').not('.textarea-placeholder').is(':empty');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution checks for text nodes too, so if the div contais text it will be considered not empty

```js
function checkEmptyExceptPlaceholder(query) {
  const otherElements = $(query).contents().filter(function() {
    if (this.nodeType == 3) // Text nodes
      return !!this.wholeText.trim(); // Empty text nodes will be forgiven
    return this.id !== 'textarea-placeholder';
  });
  return !otherElements.length;
}

// Contains only the placeholder, so should return true
console.log('is textarea1 empty? ', checkEmptyExceptPlaceholder('#textarea1'));

// Contains the placeholder, text and other elements, so should return false
console.log('is textarea2 empty? ', checkEmptyExceptPlaceholder('#textarea2'));

// Contains the placeholder and text, but no other elements, and yet should return false
console.log('is textarea3 empty? ', checkEmptyExceptPlaceholder('#textarea3'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="textarea1" contenteditable="true">
  <span id="textarea-placeholder" data-text="Enter comment"></span>
</div>

<div id="textarea2" contenteditable="true">
  <span id="textarea-placeholder" data-text="Enter comment"></span> abc text inside div
  <a></a> //other elements
  <p></p> // other elements
</div>

<div id="textarea3" contenteditable="true">
  <span id="textarea-placeholder" data-text="Enter comment"></span> abc text inside div
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `.not()`

```js
var isFirstEmpty = ($('#textarea *').not('#textarea-placeholder').length == 0);
console.log('Is empty: ' + isFirstEmpty);
var isSecondEmpty = ($('#textarea2 *').not('#textarea-placeholder2').length == 0);
console.log('Is empty: ' + isSecondEmpty);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="textarea"  contenteditable="true">
  <span id="textarea-placeholder" data-text="Enter comment"></span>
</div>

<div id="textarea2"  contenteditable="true">
  <span id="textarea-placeholder2" data-text="Enter comment"></span>
  abc text inside div
  <a></a>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javaScript for that

```js
if (document.getElementById("text").value == "") {
  console.log('No text')
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

[Check out the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vf5o17j8/)